# Python regex fails to match after number

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have this string

```
RESULT: Avg Time:                     53.49402644us (2336.71 MB/s)
```

I want to capture `RESULT: Avg Time:                     53.49402644us (2336.71`

My regular expression fails to catch anything after `53.49402644`

Here it is:

```
result = re.compile(r'RESULT: Avg Time:.*\(\d*\.\d*')
```

It would result in:

```
RESULT: Avg Time:                     53.49402644
```

[EDIT]

As explained by wjandrea and Jan Wilamowski in the comments section, I used to retrieve the info by

```
result_match = result.search(string)
print(result_match)
```

This would trim the result, and should rather be accessed by using group().

```
print(result_match.group())
```

Comment: `re.match(r'RESULT: Avg Time:.*\(\d*\.\d*', s).group()` gives `'RESULT: Avg Time:                     53.49402644us (2336.71'` which is what you want, right?

Comment: How are you using `result`? You need to provide a [mre]. FWIW, I can sort of reproduce the issue if I just print the bare match object, cause the end gets cut off: `<re.Match object; span=(0, 60), match='RESULT: Avg Time:                     53.49402644>`

Comment: @Jan Wilamowski Yes using online regex compilers, the output is correctly produced,; however, when inside python interpreter it doesn't. Don't know why.

Comment: I ran the above code through my Python interpreter and it produced the result. As wjandrea asked, how are you getting the result from your input?

Comment: @wjandrea yes printing the match object is how I view my output also.

Comment: Your error seems to be in how you access the result. Give it a try with `match = re.match()` and then `match.group()`

Comment: @JanWilamowski I get the result by performing result_match = result.search("str") and then print(result_match)

Comment: @Nour Yeah, like I said, the end gets cut off if you do that. Get the full matching text from `result_match.group()`.

Comment: What you get from match and search is called a match object, not a simple string: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects

Comment: Yeah I thought that the match object would hold the whole matched string, and only if I have groups in my regex "( )" then those can be accessed using .group(x)

Comment: It still doesn't match for me, for example I add us in the regular expression, it returns None!

Comment: Please update the question with the complete code you're using.

Comment: @JanWilamowski wjandrea, Okay now I tried again with .group() and I am able to find the whole text. Seems I mistyped it last time with group only without parentheses. Thank you again.